# What is the proper implementation of a base entity class in clean architecture approach?

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, clean-architecture

I'm studying clean architecture approach on .NET and almost all recent examples use domain events logic inside the base entity class. Here is one example:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace CleanArchitecture.Domain.Common;

public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    // This can easily be modified to be BaseEntity<T> and public T Id to support different key types.
    // Using non-generic integer types for simplicity
public int Id { get; set; }

private readonly List<BaseEvent> _domainEvents = new();

[NotMapped]
public IReadOnlyCollection<BaseEvent> DomainEvents => _domainEvents.AsReadOnly();

public void AddDomainEvent(BaseEvent domainEvent)
{
    _domainEvents.Add(domainEvent);
}

public void RemoveDomainEvent(BaseEvent domainEvent)
{
    _domainEvents.Remove(domainEvent);
}

public void ClearDomainEvents()
{
    _domainEvents.Clear();
}
}
```

All entities are derived from these type of base classes. Normally there happens to be some entities which don't need domain events. Shouldn't I make different base classes (or an interface) for this situation? Why these libraries prefer to derive all entities from a base class which includes event logic?

Thank you!

Libraries reviewed:

https://github.com/jasontaylordev/CleanArchitecture

https://github.com/ardalis/CleanArchitecture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean Architecture itself does not "require" domain events. Domain events are rather a "tool" of Domain-Driven Design (DDD). If your design does not require any domain events then you should also not derive from such a base class. In fact, generally speaking, I would avoid any base class for your entities unless this base class really provides a clear benefit.

Here is how I setup my Clean Architecture projects usually: https://youtu.be/1IE8RC-IOSE